# What's South Korea's country name in API?

Tags: api

**[SOLVED]** the official name is **Korea, Republic of**. You can's miss any white space when you use it.

I am using Last.FM API, when I try [geo.getTopArtists](https://www.last.fm/api/show/geo.getTopArtists)(Get the most popular artists on Last.fm by country), I need to input a parameter ：

```
country (Required) : A country name, as defined by the ISO 3166-1 country names standard.
```

Then I checked ISO 3116-1, and found South Korea's name is *Korea, Republic of*
but it doesn't work. Then I tried *korea, southkorea,koreaofrepublic* ,all failed.
What should I input?

```
http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=korea&api_key=aa652ac51995d952d83d12093d25d9d9&format=json
```

Comment: Isn't it just `KR`?

Comment: Try KR, or KOR.

Comment: sorry guys, all failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

It should be **ISO 3166-1**  country name  standard .

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1

Comment: Thank you!  I notice that I miss a white space .Now it works! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you copy/paste this link in your browser, you will get the complete list of countries
that are supported by Rest Countries Api.

https://restcountries.com/v2/all

My suggestion is to do it in Firefox, because, list will be formatted in a readable way.

From there, you can search for the any data you might need.

For example, in the case of South Korea, you would go to the link, type 'korea' in the search bar, and you would get two results ( for North and South Korea), and when you expand the JSON object, you could read the exact name of the country as they listed it in their API. "Korea (Republic of)" in this case.

Comment: That appears to be a completely different API. Last.fm could call South Korea “Flooby,” and it wouldn’t help OP.